# LINQ query to conditionally filter on a where clause and select the values from another table

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have the following tables (limited to the scope of this post).

**OrderItem** / `DbSet<OrderItem> OrderItems`

```
Id 
OrderId 
ProductId
```

**Product** / `DbSet<Product> Products`

```
Id
Name
```

**ProductCategory** / `DbSet<ProductCategory> ProductCategories (many-to-many)`

```
CategoryId
ProductId
```

I have a function that returns an IQueryable. I need the ability to determine if a `categoryId` is passed and conditionally do a where clause hopefully in line.

Ideally, I don't want to join on the ProductCategory table, since I don't want to get any of the category information back... but if I must, I'll need to do a distinct so the I don't get repeated results back. I only want to return results of the order and product information.

I'd like to stick with linq query examples vs. linq method. The actual query is a little more complicated than what I've displayed here and I'd prefer not to rewrite it.

See the commented section in the code, it has the original sql that I need to translate into the linq query

```
public IQueryable<OrderReport> GetOrderQuery(int? categoryId = null)
{ 

    var query = from p in Products
        join oi in OrderItems on p.Id equals oi.ProductId
        join o in Orders on oi.OrderId equals o.Id
        
        // this is the sql that I need to translate into a linq query
        /* WHERE (@categoryId IS NULL OR product.Id in (select ProductId from 
        ProductCategory where CategoryId = @categoryId)) */
        
        select new OrderReport
        {
            OrderId = o.Id
            ProductName = p.Name
            ....

        }

    return query;
}
```

I tried something like this but I get an error

```
if (categoryId != null)
{
             
    query = query.Where(p => ProductCategories.Any(c => c.ProductId == p.Id && c.CategoryId == categoryId));
               
}
```

Comment: Please share the error details

Comment: Don't join, use navigation properties.

Answer (score 0):

checked your code. I wrote a sample of the same code with lambda expressions. i also modified your source code and it was implemented. Both of the following methods provide the same output.

lambda syntax:

```
MyDataBaseEntities db = new MyDataBaseEntities();
public IQueryable<OrderReport> GetOrderQuery(int? categoryId = null)
{

   var query = db.Products
    .Join(
        db.OrderItems,
        prud => prud.Id,
        oite => oite.ProductId,
        (prud, oite) => new { Product = prud, OrderItem = oite })
     .Join(
        db.Orders,
        selec => selec.OrderItem.OrderId,
        orde => orde.Id,
        (selec, orde) => new { selec.Product, selec.OrderItem, Order = orde })
     .Where(p => db.ProductCategories.Any(c => c.ProductId == p.Product.Id && c.CategoryId == categoryId))
    .Select(c => new OrderReport
    {
       OrderId = c.Order.Id,
       ProductId =  c.Product.Id,
       ProductName = c.Product.Name
    }).AsQueryable();

   return query;
}
```

linq query syntax

```
public IQueryable<OrderReport> GetOrderQuery(int? categoryId = null)
{

    var query = from p in db.Products
       join oi in db.OrderItems on p.Id equals oi.ProductId
       join o in db.Orders on oi.OrderId equals o.Id

       select new OrderReport
       {
           ProductId = p.Id,
           OrderId = o.Id,
           ProductName = p.Name
       };


   query = query.Where(p => db.ProductCategories.Any(c => c.ProductId == p.ProductId && c.CategoryId == categoryId));
   
   return query;
}
```

I used this class for testing

```
public class OrderReport
{
   public int OrderId { get; set; }
   public int ProductId { get; set; }
   public string ProductName { get; set; }
   public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
}
```